# How to get a pointer to the beginning of a file in C++

Tags: c++, unix, stdio

Is it possible in C++ to somehow get a pointer to the beginning of an opened file so that it ( the pointer ) can be passed to the unix write function together with the size of the file?

Just to be clear: I want to pass the whole file to a write-like function - how do I do this?

Comment: You are not being very clear - why can't you use fopen() or open()?

Comment: You can just pass around the file stream and use seekp(ios_base::beg) to set current position to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "pointer"?  Memory pointer, file position, file pointer, handle...?  Maybe a snippet of the relevant code would come in handy to understand the question better.

Comment: I don't have any code yet - I'm looking for a possibility to send files using write and read functions - is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can just [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) the complete file, and then pass this pointer to write. You'll have to open it using the `open()`, not `fopen()` though.

Comment: and get the length of the file from the fstat(2) system call after you've opened the file.

Answer (score 4):

[sendfile()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) is specifically for this purpose on POSIX platforms when sending over the network, and the kernel handles the intricacies of doing it.

Comment: Sendfile is (a) not portable; (b) only supported for some destinations (e.g., only sockets)

Comment: This bypasses userspace! Meaning you cannot actually do anything with the data, you can just order the kernel to copy it around! The question is unclear if that is all that should be done. If it is, this should be the fastest possible way.

Comment: "not portable" irked me somewhat and I did a lookup. You are absolutely right! You can only use this function in the linux world, other unixoids or windows don't know this command or implement it differently. Still, if you target linux only, it should be the best possible way.